# CountdownLabel check if finished

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nstimer, countdown

I'm sandboxing a little timer app.
I'm using  [this cocoapod](https://github.com/suzuki-0000/CountdownLabel)

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import CountdownLabel

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet weak var moreBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lessBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var gifview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: CountdownLabel!
    var mins = 25
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCountdown()
        updateTimer(min: mins)
    }
    
    // MARK: Buttons
    
    @IBAction func startPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        countdownLabel.start()
    }
    @IBAction func lessPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if(mins > 0){
        mins = mins - 5
        updateTimer(min: mins)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func morePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        mins = mins + 5
        updateTimer(min: mins)
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: Helper Func
    
    func updateTimer(min: Int){
        countdownLabel.setCountDownTime(minutes: 60*Double(min))
    }
    
    func setupCountdown(){
        countdownLabel.textColor = .black
        countdownLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Courier", size:UIFont.labelFontSize)
        countdownLabel.animationType = .Evaporate
    }
}
```

Now I want to check if the timer is finished (can use this cocoapod built in function: countdownLabel.isFinished() ).

But I have no clue WHERE and HOW I can check this.
As an example: if(countdownLabel.isFinished()){countdownLabel.text = "Finished"}

Thanks for your help

Comment: The answer you are looking for is in the link you posted. You don't need to check it. I see a `countdownFinished()` delegate method.

Comment: @Desdenova you should post that as an answer.

Comment: But where can I use this? In the viewDidLoad?

Comment: I would be soooo happy if you can quickly copy and paste this line: f(countdownLabel.isFinished()){countdownLabel.text = "Finished"} (or the meaning of this line) into my code and send it as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not tested, I'm just following the document you posted. Seems like you don't need to check if `countdownLabel.isFinished()`, because there is a delegate method for that which will be called as soon as it is finished.

Set up the delegate in `func setupCountdown()`:

```
countdownLabel.countdownDelegate = self
```

Conform the protocol in your view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CountdownLabelDelegate
```

Add the delegate method in your view controller:

```
func countdownFinished() {
    // This method will be called when the countdown finishes. 
    // Do whatever you need here. 
}
```